# How to customize MUI X Data Grid Toolbar to only show icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

```
`function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  slots={{
    toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
/>`
```

My Result

[image: My Result]

I want to remove the columns, filters, density and export texts here. I just want to use icons
what can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localeText` prop or create your own custom toolbar. demo link is given in this discussion: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3148

```
function CustomToolbar() {
  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
<DataGrid
  localeText={{ toolbarColumns: "", toolbarFilters: "", toolbarDensity: "", toolbarExport: "" }}
  {...data}
  slots={{
    toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
/>
```